# Query with multiple parameter not working Error - An expression of non-Boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I made an ado.net function which take string with values from query-string separated by comma which are used get values from database using Like Query,
multiple like are used in query which are generated by function.

Here My code. Please tell error in Function

```
public void GetData()
{
    System.Data.DataTable DT = new System.Data.DataTable();
    DT = BLL.GetProjectByLike("9,55");
    if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = DT;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}

public DataTable GetProjectByLike(string ID)
{
    string Query = string.Format("Select * From Project where @SCATID");
    SqlParameter[] SqlP = new SqlParameter[1];
    SqlP[0] = new SqlParameter("@SCATID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    SqlP[0].Value = MultipleLikeQuery("Sub_Cate_id", ID);
    DT = DLL.GetDatatableWithQueryP(Query, SqlP);
    return DT;
}

public string MultipleLikeQuery(string ColumnName, string Values)
{
    string Result = "";
    string[] strArrValue = Values.Split(',');
    foreach(string SAV in strArrValue)
    {
        Result += ColumnName + " " + "LIKE" + " " + "'%" + SAV + "%'" + " " + "or" + " ";
    }
    Result = Result.Substring(0, Result.Length - 3);
    return Result;
}

public DataTable GetDatatableWithQueryP(string Query, SqlParameter[] sqlp)
{
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(strcon))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(Query, SqlCon);
            SqlCmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlp);
            SqlDataReader DR = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            DT.Load(DR);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            SqlCon.Close();
        }
    }
    return DT;
}
```

Comment: can you show us the result sql command that you are trying to execute?

Comment: I don't think you can assign a complete where expression as SqlParameter to a SqlCommand ... it's just for passing values ...